# Order query results by...?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First up, I should say that I'm finding it very hard to express the following problem in a few short words, hence the awful question title.  Suggestions to improve are very welcome.

Now to the real question...

Given the following sample, unordered data for customers and invoices...

**Edit**  I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2642) for the following

**Customer data**

```
customer_id   name
------------------
1             Gary
2             Jeremy
3             Marcia
4             Danielle
```

**Invoice data**

```
invoice_id   customer_id   created_date   amount
------------------------------------------------
1            1             2008-01-01     500.00
2            1             2011-01-01     600.00
3            1             2012-01-01     100.00
4            1             2012-01-01     550.00
5            2             2008-01-01     600.00
6            2             2012-01-01     200.00
7            2             2013-01-01     1000.00
8            3             2012-01-01     300.00
9            3             2013-01-01     100.00
10           3             2009-01-01     250.00
11           4             2010-01-01     300.00
12           4             2011-01-01     700.00
13           4             2012-01-01     500.00
```

...how could a query be written to return the data in the following way...

1. The oldest invoice in the first row.  If more than 1 invoice of the same age, then, of those invoices with the same age, the invoice of the greatest amount.  If more than 1 invoice of the same age and amount, sorting becomes irrelevant.
2. The next oldest invoice *for the same customer as the previous row*, in the second row.  Again, if more than 1 invoice of the same age, the invoice of the greatest amount.  If more than 1 invoice of the same age and amount, sorting becomes irrelevant.
3. Repeating #2 until there are no more invoices for that customer.
4. The next oldest invoice for a different customer.  If more than 1 invoice of the same, then, of those invoice with the same age, the invoice of the greatest amount.  If more than 1 invoice of the same age and amount, sorting becomes irrelevant.
5. Repeat #2 for the same customer as #4.
6. Repeating #5 until there are no more invoices for that customer.
7. Repeat #4, #5, #6

So, for the sample data above, the desired results would be...

```
customer_name   invoice_id   created_date   amount
--------------------------------------------------
Jeremy          5            2008-01-01     600.00   <-- this is the joint "oldest" invoice with id 1 but has a greater amount.
Jeremy          6            2012-01-01     200.00   <-- this is the next "oldest" invoice for the same customer as the previous row.
Jeremy          7            2013-01-01     1000.00
Gary            1            2008-01-01     500.00   <-- no more invoice for previous customer, so this is the next "oldest" invoice for a new customer
Gary            2            2011-01-01     600.00
Gary            4            2012-01-01     550.00  <-- same age as inv_id 3 but larger amount
Gary            3            2012-01-01     100.00
Marcia          10           2009-01-01     250.00
Marcia          8            2012-01-01     300.00
Marcia          9            2013-01-01     100.00
Danielle        11           2010-01-01     300.00
Danielle        12           2011-01-01     700.00
Danielle        13           2012-01-01     500.00
```

To give the wider context for this question, the results will be used to chase payment for invoices, oldest and most "expensive" being the highest priority but then also to see all invoices for a customer grouped together.

P.S. I'm working with MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I forgot customer. I fixed my query. Customers are sorted by name.

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't know sqlfiddle.com. It's awesome :). Thx for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this works :)

```
with ordering as
(
  select
  row_number() over (order by o.created_date asc, o.amount desc) num,
  customer_id,
  customer_name
  from
  (
    select
    min(i.created_date) 
    over (partition by c.customer_id) as min_created_date,
    max(i.amount) 
    over (partition by c.customer_id, i.created_date) max_date_amount,
    c.name as customer_name,
    c.customer_id as customer_id,
    i.invoice_id,
    i.created_date,
    i.amount
    from
    invoice i
    join customer c on i.customer_id = c.customer_id
  )o
  where o.min_created_date = o.created_date
  and o.max_date_amount = o.amount
)
select
ord.customer_name,
i.invoice_id,
i.created_date,
i.amount
from
ordering ord
join invoice i on i.customer_id = ord.customer_id
order by ord.num asc, i.created_date asc, i.amount desc;
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. The 1st result row is correct to return invoice_id 5 but the next row should be the next oldest invoice for the same customer (id 6) but it's id 1 which is for a different customer.

Comment: @SmallestDruid Yea, I fixed that.

Comment: the edit doesn't return invoice id 5 (the oldest invoice) as the 1st row now (which was correct), but instead id 10 (because the first order by is on customer name).

Comment: @SmallestDruid so you want to order Customers by their oldest invoice date?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a SQL Fiddle reference for the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna throw this in here as an alternative to the already accepted answer.

```
SELECT temp.name,
    temp.Invoice_Id,
    temp.created_Date,
    temp.amount
FROM(
  SELECT 
    c.name,
    i.invoice_id,
    i.created_date,
    i.amount,  
    min(i.created_date) over (partition by c.customer_id) as min_created_date,
    max(i.customer_id) over (partition by i.created_Date, i.amount ) as customerId
  FROM
    Customer c
  LEFT JOIN 
    Invoice i
  on 
    c.customer_ID=i.Customer_ID
) temp

ORDER BY  temp.min_created_date, 
    temp.customerId desc, 
    temp.created_Date, 
    temp.amount desc
```

Comment: this also gives the correct result, thanks for the contribution